# Ghub Script: Drag mouse down and autocliking by pressing left mouse button (LUA)

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

So basically I was trying to make the thing explained in the title using Ghub Lua scripting mechanics, posting the code below of what I have rn:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
if  IsMouseButtonPressed(1)then
   repeat
   MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
   PressMouseButton(1)
   Sleep(1,2)
   ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end
end
end
```

The problem is, sometimes it just stops midway going down, sometimes it just doesnt click at all. Have tried multiple ways of going around this, including changing what button is being pressed on the mouse, for now it's  IsMouseButtonPressed(5), which works fine, but my goal is to get it working while pressing MouseButton(1). If it was any possible, I'd appriciate any help from you guys, thanks in advance, hope I gave you all necessary info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because it is impossible to simultaneously simulate LMB press/release and monitor its state.
The workaround is below:

**Step 0.**
You are about to modify the behavior of Left Mouse Button.
This is a potentially dangerous operation: you can do almost nothing on your computer without LMB.
So you must create a "spare LMB".
For example, if you don't use Mouse Button 8, you can make it acting like a clone of LMB.
Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen, SYSTEM tab).
Assign "Primary click" to your physical MB#8.
Now, if something goes wrong and your LMB stops working, you can press MB#8 instead of LMB.

---

**Step 1.**
Do you use Mouse Button 4 ("back") in the game?

- If YES (some action is set to MB#4 in the game), proceed to "Step 2".
- If NO (the game ignores MB#4 press), skip "Step 2" and proceed to "Step 3".

---

**Step 2.**
You have to remap game action from MB#4 to some other key.
Do the following:

- choose keyboard key you don't currently use in the game
  (let's assume the `F12` key is not currently used)
- go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen, KEYS tab);
  assign `F12` to your physical MB#4
- go to your game settings;
  set the game action to `F12` instead of MB#4

Now when you press physical MB#4, the game receives `F12` and activates the game action.
Skip "Step 3" and proceed to "Step 4".

---

**Step 3.**
Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen).
Unassign standard command "Back" from physical MB#4 (click and select DISABLE from the drop-down menu).
Disabled MB#4 will look like a white circle with black inside.

---

**Step 4.**
Set the script (see below).

---

**Step 5.**
Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen, SYSTEM tab).
Assign "Back" to your physical LMB.
You will see a warning about a potentially dangerous operation.
Allow this operation because you have the "spare LMB" if something goes wrong.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      PressMouseButton(1)
      if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
         repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
            Sleep(10)
            if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then break end
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
            Sleep(10)
            PressMouseButton(1)
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)  -- 4 = "Back"
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   end
end
```

Comment: Great idea, but what if I tried to simulate the key press and then remapping the fire button ingame to that of a key and it worked, but it was pretty inconvinient for most situations to switch between weapons. Alternatively, I could create a second profile which simulates the press of a key and just a press of a key by pressing Mouse 1 button, but that would be pretty lot's of profiles gotta say ))

Comment: The method of remapping of fire button in game usually does not work: if you assign two different buttons for fire, these two buttons do not work independently (the game does not allow you to press 2nd fire button while 1st fire is pressed).

Comment: I think your soulution is the best I can ever get, really, but I somehow managed to make only two separate profiles for the game, one being autoclicking and pulling mouse down, the other is just emulating the press of a fire ket and just pulling the mouse down, works simply by cycling through them with DPI button. I think your solution is a bit too complex, but if I get any troubles with my "rig" I will simply use yours one instead. In all appreciation, I am glad that someone actually responded with a workable solution not after 3 years or so to such a specific problem, thank you again mate )

Comment: @Dainzh - `one being autoclicking` - Interesting.  How exactly your profile works?  How fire buttons are mapped in the game?  What arguments you pass to PressMouseButton and IsMouseButtonPressed?

Comment: This is for a autoclick and dragging down:
`EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
if  IsMouseButtonPressed(1)then
   repeat
   Sleep(1,2)
   PressKey("v")
   MoveMouseRelative(0,3)
   Sleep(1,2)
   ReleaseKey("v")
   until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end
end
end`

Comment: This is for simple drag: 
`EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
if IsMouseButtonPressed(1)then
   repeat
   MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
   PressKey("v")
   Sleep(1,2)
   until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
ReleaseKey("v")
end
end
end`

Comment: I simply mapped key to fire ingame, and I cycle through those two profiles with a DPI button now. And I still have my functional LMB, just need to turn off the capslock.

Comment: @Dainzh - OK, you have mapped `V` for fire.  But where does LMB mapped to in the game?  If both `V` and LMB mapped for fire then it means the game allows them to work independently (`V` works while LMB is down) which is not true in other games.

Comment: LMB is not mapped in the game for anything, it works as normal in the main menu, but the game allows also only one key being mapped to specific action. Your variant is useful if the game doesn't allow that change, which is quite useful I say.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, your method is more simple and 100% workable.  The only problem is that when you click LMB in a text field (for example, to enter your name at the beginning of a game) `v` symbol is automatically inserted there, so you have to temporary disable the script by CapsLock.