# Logitech Lua Script Left Mouse Button Spam on Holding Lmb

Tags: random, lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Logitech Lua Script:

This should be an easy one i thought

**Goal: Spam Leftclick on random inervall while left Mouse Button is pressed.**

Somehow i can't get it to work and it only will only click 1 time. I really would appreciate some help

I tried sth like this with press mousebutton1 and with playmacros for lmb down and up

I guess it will stop on ReleaseMousebutton, but i dont know how to work around that.

```
elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
    repeat
         PressMouseButton(1) 
         Sleep(math.random(111, 143)) 
         ReleaseMouseButton(1) 
         Sleep(math.random(111, 143))
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
end
```

(This is implemented into an existing, working script)

Comment: The simplest way is to change "Shoot" action binding in the game settings from LMB to keyboard key "P".  And replace `PressMouseButton(1)/ReleaseMouseButton(1)` with `PressKey("P")/ReleaseKey("P")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was my goal at first, but you cant reassign the lmb/rmb in the game i play so i try to work around that without success for now :/ @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68704074/1847592) solve the problem?

Comment: Hm not really, its not about a shooter but about movement in an mmorpg (movement via leftkick). If you remember This topic" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639990/logitech-lua-script-randomized-button-press-in-repeat-loop-on-random-sleep-timer?noredirect=1#comment129357501_72639990" you already helped me with, i lately implemented a Mouseclick after the "s"key whick cancels an animation. When starting holding the lmb for movement while i am still on the button to run the scripted rotation(mb5), then release mb5(still holding down lmb to move), he doesnt

Comment: recognize the lmb for movement so i thought i could fix this with doing sth. like spamming the lmb while holding down lmb to start moving in this case. Maybe you also know another workaround tho @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: Just for good measure, this is what i am working with atm. https://pastebin.com/kBbeZhrg. Basically a skill rotation on mb5, one with mb5 and shift and one with mb4. Its not pretty but works pretty good so far. The problem is just that while i hold down mb5 -> Press lmb for movement -> release mb5 he stops recognizing the movement from lmb and thats sth i wanna fix if possible @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: Lmb movement stops working because of line 21-24 as far as i can see it. I hope u can follow me on this :) i am not experienced in scripting but i am eager to learn!

Comment: btw. movement key "lmb" can't be remapped ingame.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because it is impossible to simultaneously simulate LMB press/release and monitor its state.
The workaround is below:

**Step 0.**
You are about to modify the behavior of Left Mouse Button.
This is a potentially dangerous operation: you can do almost nothing on your computer without LMB.
So you must create a "spare LMB".
For example, if you don't use Mouse Button 8, you can make it acting like a clone of LMB.
Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen, SYSTEM tab).
Assign "Primary click" to your physical MB#8.
Now, if something goes wrong and your LMB stops working, you can press MB#8 instead of LMB.

---

**Step 1.**
Do you use Mouse Button 4 ("back") in the game?

- If YES (some action is set to MB#4 in the game), proceed to "Step 2".
- If NO (the game ignores MB#4 press), skip "Step 2" and proceed to "Step 3".

---

**Step 2.**
You have to remap game action from MB#4 to some other key.
Do the following:

- choose keyboard key you don't currently use in the game
  (let's assume the `F12` key is not currently used)
- go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen, KEYS tab);
  assign `F12` to your physical MB#4
- go to your game settings;
  set the game action to `F12` instead of MB#4

Now when you press physical MB#4, the game receives `F12` and activates the game action.
Skip "Step 3" and proceed to "Step 4".

---

**Step 3.**
Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen).
Unassign standard command "Back" from physical MB#4 (click and select DISABLE from the drop-down menu).
Disabled MB#4 will look like a white circle with black inside.

---

**Step 4.**
Set the script (see below).

---

**Step 5.**
Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen, SYSTEM tab).
Assign "Back" to your physical LMB.
You will see a warning about a potentially dangerous operation.
Allow this operation because you have the "spare LMB" if something goes wrong.

```
-- CapsLock turns autoclicker ON/OFF
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
         repeat
            PressMouseButton(1) 
            Sleep(math.random(111, 143)) 
            ReleaseMouseButton(1) 
            Sleep(math.random(111, 143))
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)  -- 4 = "Back"
      end
      PressMouseButton(1)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   end
end
```

Comment: I fooled around with it a bit and it seems to work. I deletet the Capslock function and "PressMouseButton(1)" before the 2nd elseif. Now i get always 1 Lmb Click when clicking Lmb once and button spam while holding. Should be ok like that i think or did i mess sth essential up with that?

Comment: A Problem Created by ur fix is now, when i hold lmb to walk(spamming) and press mb4 on my mouse to activate the command from line 41 to the end of the script(Pressing "e" and "r" at the same time with a short delay of "r". When i hold down lmb and press mb4 multiple times, nothing happens(what is fine) but after releasing lmb he executes every previous mb4 presses. I think this can be fixed easily by cleaning up my code for the action?

Comment: This cannot be fixed.  GHUB sends you the next event only after you finished with the previous one.  Can you simply bind a GHUB macro to MB4 and remove its logic from the Lua code?

Comment: Ah ok i understand. I could but i dont wanna have a macro with non ramdom time values due to possible detection :/. It also works like it is now! Not perfect but i can deal with it :) Thanks a lot mate!