# I can't figure out what the error is. I wrote a macro for GHub in lua, it works, but sometimes it doesn't stop working

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I wrote an autoclicker macro for the game, in Lua. Everything works as it should, but sometimes he continues his work even when he should have already completed it. I can't figure out what's wrong.According to the idea, the script should run with Caps Lock turned on and simultaneously pressing the left and right mouse buttons (aiming and firing), and stop working when the left mouse button is released.I have no experience in programming, I have just started my training, so maybe I don't see an obvious mistake, please help.
Here is part of the script :

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
repeat


Sleep(40)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(40)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(40)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(40)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 0)
Sleep(40)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 0)

if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end

ReleaseMouseButton(1)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
PressMouseButton(1)



Sleep(40)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(40)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(40)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(40)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(40)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)

if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end

ReleaseMouseButton(1)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
PressMouseButton(1)


until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end
end
end
```

Comment: How to simultaneously simulate pressing LMB and monitor its state: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68704074/ghub-script-drag-mouse-down-and-autocliking-by-pressing-left-mouse-button-lua/68724556

Comment: The more simple solution is to remap "Shoot" action in the game settings from LMB to some other key (for example "P" keyboard key) and simulate pressing this key `PressKey("P")` instead of `PressMouseButton(1)`

Answer (score 0):

The last statement in your `reapeat until` block is `PressmouseButton(1)` and your condition to stop the loop is `not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)`.

So in an ideal world your loop would never stop due to that condition. If you just pressed the mousebutton, how can it be not pressed? There is only one reason:

From the manual:

> The PressMouseButton() function is used to simulate a mouse button
> press. **NOTE: Calling IsMouseButtonPressed immediately afterwards, will
> likely return the previous state. It will take a few milliseconds for
> the operation to complete.**

That "likely" delay is what makes it stop some times.

Comment: I think I realized that I need to replace until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) with until not Is the mouse button released(1), since the button is pressed, it should be released. Thanks, I figured out which direction to move in.

Comment: that won't change much. you still have the issue with the uncertain state mentioned in the manual and what would be the purpose of doing that? the loop would then stop after one cycle so why use a loop in the first place? get out pen and paper and draw a flow chart